# Pass wrapper to LWC in datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, wrapper-class

Hello guys I am trying to pass a List of WrapperToLWC from an Apex class to a JavaScript file in order to get the wrapper and show its information in a lightning-datatable.

My Wrapper is this:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable= True)
public static List<WrapperToLWC> getListaMiembross(String nombreComunidadEnergetica){
    Id cleanId = (Id) nombreComunidadEnergetica;
    List<SObject> membersList = new List<SObject>();
    membersList = [SELECT Id, SObject1, Rol, SObject2, SObject2.Name, SObject2.Phone, SObject2.Email FROM SObject WHERE SObject1 =: cleanId ];
    List<WrapperToLWC> listToLWC = new List<WrapperToLWC>();

    for(SObject iMiembro: membersList){
        WrapperToLWC iMember = new WrapperToLWC();
        iMember.idCuenta = iMiembro.SObject2;
        iMember.idMember = iMiembro.Id;
        iMember.Name = iMiembro.SObject2.Name;
        iMember.email = iMiembro.SObject2.Email;
        iMember.phone = iMiembro.SObject2.Phone;
        iMember.rol = iMiembro.Rol;
        listToLWC.add(iMember);
    }
    System.debug('list '+ listToLWC);
    return listToLWC;
}


public class WrapperToLWC{
    @AuraEnabled public String idAccount{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String Name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String email{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String phone{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String idMember{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String rol{get;set;}
}
```

And in my javascript code I have this:

```
getWrapperInfo({name: this.name}).then(result =>{
        if(result != null){
            //What should I do in order to get the data and pass it to a lightning-datatable
        }
    })
```

And the columns of my lightning-datatble are:

```
this.columns = [
        { label: 'Nombre', fieldName: 'Name' },
        { label: 'Teléfono', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone'},
        { label: 'Correo electrónico', fieldName: 'email', type:'email' },
        { label: 'Rol', fieldName: 'rol' },
    ]
```

And my html:

```
<lightning-datatable class="table" onrowselection={handleSelectedMembers}
                    selected-rows={selectedIds} key-field='Id' data={recordsToDisplay} columns={columns}>
                </lightning-datatable>
```

Could someone help me? And put an example? Thanks

Comment: What does your Apex method look like?

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated the code

Comment: based on this post: [Call Apex Methods from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative), the only thing you are missing is assigning the result to your javascript variable, try this: `this.recordsToDisplay = result;`  inside your `if` statement. since you are already setting the datatable's data property: `data={recordsToDisplay}`